# FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

Here's my problem.  If I run the test using the ruby command the tests all pass.  However, if I use the rake test:functionals they all fail with the error below.  I'm not sure what I have to do differently to get them to pass when using the rake task, but I'd greatly appreciate any guidance you might offer.

```
#tasks_controller_test.rb
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class TasksControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    set_fixture_class :Action => 'Task'
    fixtures :Action

    setup :initialize_test

    test "the truth" do
        assert true
    end

    private
    def initialize_test
        @user = users :one
        sign_in @user
        @user.confirm!

        @task = Action :one    # Here's the line that is throwing the error.
    end
end
```

---

```
1) Error:
    test_the_truth(TasksControllerTest):
        FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find.
        test/functional/tasks_controller_test.rb:20:in `initialize_test'
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a `Task` model whose table name is `Action`. This means you should have `app/models/task.rb` and `test/fixtures/Action.yml` (or csv). Did I get that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like no one is able to solve this problem.  So I'm simply closing it at this point.  Perhaps I'll switch over to Factory_Girl or Machinist.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that Rails can't figure out what fixture to load for the test.

I assume the fixture is named Action.yml.  Does Rails accept fixture filenames that have uppercase letters?

Per the documentation at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods/set_fixture_class, the set_fixture_class is expecting a classname rather than a string.

So I would try:

```
set_fixture_class :myaction => Task
```

And I'd rename the fixture file to myaction.yml

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange way of handling the  problem.

With rails, out of the box, if you have fixtures, they will load them before each test.

You don't need to explicity load them in the controller test.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

> Rails by default automatically loads all fixtures from the
>   test/fixtures folder for your unit and functional test. Loading
>   involves three steps:

Comment: That's only true if your models map directly to the tables.  This is required because I am using a legacy database.  So my problem still remains.  :(